# SharePoint REST API to Query a Parent:Child lookup column

Tags: jquery, rest, highcharts, sharepoint-2013

I'm using HighCharts jquery library to generate reporting charts for our intranet dashboard.  All charts work fine, with the exception of being able to narrow down the data to a specific "release" in out case.

To better explain, we have two lists, A and B.

List A contains two columns... the Releases and an isCurrent column.

List B contains a those same two columns however they are lookups, as well as data columns which are populating our charts.

The issue is that if I attempt to add a filter based on if a release "isCurrent", it does not work.  The formatting for the column is Parent:Child.  When trying to implement this, it either does not work, or throws an error (An Error Has Occurred).

Below is the code we are using:

```
EngagementChartBuilder.EngagementsPieChart_COR = function () {
var load = function () {
    $.when(
        //Empire Engagements List
        EngagementChartBuilder.RESTQuery.execute("QA_TimeMgtPerRelease", "$select=Report_Group,Reason_x0020_Type,CalculatedSubtotal&$filter=(((Reason_x0020_Type%20ne%20'Weekend%20Hours')%20and%20(Reason_x0020_Type%20ne%20'After%20Hours'))%20and%20(Report_Group%20eq%20'COR'))&$top=2000")
    ).done(
        function (engagements1) {
            var dataArray = [];
            var countArray = [];

            //Get data from Empire Engagements List
            var results = engagements1.d.results;
            var filtered = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i].Report_Group == 'COR') {
                    filtered.push(results[i]);
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                var reason = filtered[i].Reason_x0020_Type;
                var hours = filtered[i].CalculatedSubtotal;
                dataArray[i] = { 'hours': hours, 'reason': reason };
            }

            countArray = EngagementChartBuilder.Utilities.buildCategoryCounts(countArray, dataArray);

            //Build Chart
            EngagementChartBuilder.Utilities.loadPieChart(countArray, "#engagementPieChart_COR", "Testing Time vs. Time Lost (COR)");
        }
    ).fail(
        function (engagements1) {
            $("#engagementPieChart_COR").html("<strong>An error has occurred.</strong>");
        }
    );
};

return {
    load: load
}
```

I have tried to use 'Parent:Child', 'Parent_x003a_Child', but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work? And when it works, then throws error? What error?

Comment: Basically if you refer to the code I provided, you will see 'Report_Group'.  This is a column within the SharePoint list we are currently querying, and this works.  We added a lookup column to a parent list, and that shows as 'Parent:Child', or in my case, 'ProjectRelease:CALCReportGroup'.  Knowing there is a 32 character limit on the static name, this becomes 'ProjectRelease:CALCReportG'.  If I use this instead of 'Report_Group', my charts will display "An error has occurred".  If I try to load the output address in a browser, I receive a 404.

Comment: You are using highcharts.net? Maybe it's worth to ask authors here: http://highcharts.codeplex.com/ ? I thought it's in pure Highcharts, but "An error has occurred" doesn't show up there.

Comment: I'm not using highcharts.net.  I'm using the actual 100% Highcharts.

Comment: Great! So recreate issue on jsFiddle, please. Or setup live demo page with that issue, I will look into this.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't recreate it publicly because the data is driven off our intranet SharePoint environment.  I apologize I'm not providing much to go on or work with, but I'm sure someone has experienced this issue with lookups and calculated columns.